# How to extract data from lists as strings, and select data by value, in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, nested-lists

**I have a dataframe like this:**

```
col1              col2
[abc, bcd, dog]   [[.4], [.5], [.9]]
[cat, bcd, def]   [[.9], [.5], [.4]]
```

the numbers in the `col2` lists describe the element (based on list index location) in `col1`. So ".4" in `col2` describes "abc" in `col1`.

I want to create 2 new columns, one that pulls only the elements in `col1` that are >= .9 in `col2`, and the other column as the number in `col2`; so ".9" for both rows.

**Result**:

```
col3     col4
[dog]   .9
[cat]   .9
```

I think going a route where removing the nested list from `col2` is fine. But that's harder than it sounds. I've been trying for an hour to remove those fing brackets.

**Attempts**:

```
spec_chars3 = ["[","]"]

for char in spec_chars3: # didn't work, turned everything to nan
    df1['avg_jaro_company_word_scores'] = df1['avg_jaro_company_word_scores'].str.replace(char, '')

df.col2.str.strip('[]') #didn't work b/c the nested list is still in a list, not a string
```

I haven't even figured out how to pull out the list index number and filter col1 on that

Comment: Hi again Max, try creating separate dataframes `df1 and df2` with `col1 and col2` respectively, so the values stored inside each cell are scalars instead of lists... perhaps your solution will be clearer once you have that

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions to populate new columns with your criteria.

```
df['col3'] = [
    [value for value, score in zip(c1, c2) if score[0] >= 0.9]
    for c1, c2 in zip(df['col1'], df['col2'])
]
df['col4'] = [
    [score[0] for score in c2 if score[0] >= 0.9]
    for c2 in df['col2']
```

Output

```
              col1                   col2   col3   col4
0  [abc, bcd, dog]  [[0.4], [0.5], [0.9]]  [dog]  [0.9]
1  [cat, bcd, def]  [[0.9], [0.5], [0.4]]  [cat]  [0.9]
```

Comment: Hey Richie - one quick question - how would i do a between two scores? tried range and np.arange but can't get that to work

Comment: you mean `if lower <= score[0] <= higher` ?

Comment: if you use Trenton's answer you can filter with `df_new = df_new[df_new['c2'].ge(lower) & df_new['c2'].le(higher)]`

Comment: haven't gotten either solution to work. I don't know why this won't work `[value for value, score in zip(c1, c2) if score[0] >= .85 < 1.0]`

Comment: nvm - i just needed to add the if in there `[value for value, score in zip(c1, c2) if score[0] >= .85 if score[0] < 1.0]`

Comment: `if 0.85 <= score[0] < 1.0`

Answer (score 2):

- Based on the explanation at the end of the question, it seems that both columns are `str` type, and need to be converted to `list` type

  - Use `.applymap` with `ast.literal_eval`.
  - If only one column is `str` type, then use `df[col] = df[col].apply(literal_eval)`
- The lists of data in each column must be extracted by using [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

  - The outer `explode` casts values from lists to scalars (i.e. `[0.4]` to `0.4`).
- Once the values are on separate rows, use [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to select data in the desired range.
- If you want to combine `df` with `df_new`, use `df.join(df_new, rsuffix='_extracted')`
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`**

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

# setup the test data: this data is lists
# data = {'c1': [['abc', 'bcd', 'dog'], ['cat', 'bcd', 'def']], 'c2': [[[.4], [.5], [.9]], [[.9], [.5], [.4]]]}

# setup the test data: this data is strings
data = {'c1': ["['abc', 'bcd', 'dog', 'cat']", "['cat', 'bcd', 'def']"], 'c2': ["[[.4], [.5], [.9], [1.0]]", "[[.9], [.5], [.4]]"]}

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# the description leads me to think the data is columns of strings, not lists
# convert the columns from string type to list type
# the following line is only required if the columns are strings
df = df.applymap(literal_eval)

# explode the lists in each column, and the explode the remaining lists in 'c2'
df_new = df.explode(['c1', 'c2'], ignore_index=True).explode('c2')

# use Boolean Indexing to select the desired data
df_new = df_new[df_new['c2'] >= 0.9]

# display(df_new)
    c1   c2
2  dog  0.9
3  cat  1.0
4  cat  0.9
```